# Why cant i see the burndown chart decline after I resolve sub-task that had story points in greenhopper?

Tags: task, jira, jira-agile, user-stories, burndowncharts

We have subdivided a bigger story into some more sub-tasks. But if we close the sub tasks have no effect on the burndown chart which is demotivating. Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: Provide much more information and some code. How should anybody solve your problem without knowing what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

How are you tracking work in the burndown chart - by story points or hours logged. To see a decrease you will need to have had an Original Estimate or Estimated Story Points. And then you will have had to log hours or have a workflow that sets the Remaining Estimate to 0 when you close the subtask